# Refacoring in Javascript

Tags: javascript, refactoring

Is there a cleaner way to write this?

```
function foo(a,b,c){
  if ( (a < 0) || (b < 0) || (c < 0) ){
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

This function doesn't seem DRY...

Thanks

Comment: How about using a loop ? `this.arguments` ?

Comment: Why does the function not return anything if the condition doesn't match?

Comment: @RayonDabre excuse me... `this.arguments` ?

Comment: `return ![a, b, c].some(x => x < 0)`

Comment: @naomik, Excused... What is wrong with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it really

```
// es6
const foo = (a,b,c) => !(a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0)

// es5
function foo(a,b,c) {
  return !(a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Naomik. I was trying to think of another way but wasn't sure. I liked the es5 example! Appreciate it